# How to reset form after form submitting?

Tags: forms, reset

I have one search form with search button and some field, when I put value in form field and click on search button then come back on form by clicking on link(modify search form) then form value does not reset...Please check it here(http://dev.viawebgroup.com/search/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>

function test(){
var input = document.getElementById('search');
input.value = '';
};

</script>
```

Add onload to the body:

```
<button onclick="test()">Clear</button>
```

Add id to input field:

```
<input type="text" id="search">
```

Comment: <script language="JavaScript">
 function resetForm(){
   window.onload=function(){
var searchInput = document.GetElementById('SearchInputId');
searchInput.value = "";
};
 } 
</script>
<input class="submit" type="reset" value="Clear" onClick="resetForm();"/>

Is it right?
When I am using this code, then nothing is happing.. please help me..

Comment: Refer to my edit i made to my answer. It will reset the input field to empty every time the page is loaded

Comment: I just want to reset form by clicking on clear button as you can see in (http://dev.viawebgroup.com/search/)

Comment: OHHH, instead on the onload in the body. Just use the function in the onclick="" of the clear button

Comment: So you want it to reset when you go back?

Answer (score 0):

**Fatal flaw rests form befor data is sent**
The simplest way I found is

```
onsubmit="this.reset()"
```

Just put this in the form tag and all's well, simple yet efective.
I someone wanted a button excluesivly for form reset I would use onclick and write the reset in a function like this.

```
function clform()
{
 documentgetElementById('myform').reset();
}
```

The first is tried and true, the second I just wrote but should work.
The function works well used in a onbeforeunload event in the body.
I have been working on this problem my self because the page I wrote is dynamically updated and was keeping form data when back button of browser was used. I also used PHP to reload the page after submission and onfocus to reload the page when form is selected so input is on a fresh page and not the dynamically updated page.